# POST WYSIWYG-Text-Editor

Tags: javascript, php

I'm sorry I do not know english
Short'll try to explain short

I don't know Javascript at all, php is very little

I'm trying to use the "Responsive WYSIWYG Text Editor with jQuery and Bootstrap - LineControl Editor" editor

No problem getting data from database like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#txtEditor").Editor();
            $("#txtEditor").Editor("setText", "<?php echo $my_database?>");
            });

<textarea id="txtEditor" name="message"></textarea >
```

The problem is a: I can't submit, **echo $_POST['message'];**

Second problem:
Image code in editor does not send ajax 
Sample code: `<div>Hello World</div><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAR0AAABMCAYAAABQzSrQI...=">`
No problem sending "Hello World" text, but does not send image code

```
var message = $("#txtEditor").Editor("getText");
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: message,
success: function(dataResult){
}
});
```

Can you help with these two issues?
Thank you from now

Answer (score 1):

Typically these WYSIWYG editors replace the `<textarea>` with divs and other markup which makes it not a form field anymore. You'll need to use javascript to get the editor content on submit and either submit it via ajax or add it to another form field:

```
<textarea id="txtEditor" name="txtEditor"></textarea>
<textarea id="txtEditorContent" name="txtEditorContent" style="display:none;"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<script>
$("input:submit").click(function(){
    $('#txtEditorContent').text($('#txtEditor').Editor("getText"));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply
Yes, it worked

It is for PHP and writing to text database and rearranging

```
<textarea id="txtEditor"></textarea>
<textarea id="txtEditorContent" name="txtEditorContent" style="display:none;"></textarea>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#txtEditor").Editor();
      $("#txtEditor").Editor("setText", "<?php echo addslashes($my_database); ?>");  // From the database into the editor
        $("input:submit").click(function(){
          $('#txtEditorContent').text($('#txtEditor').Editor("getText")); // PHP, echo $_POST['txtEditorContent']
        });

   });
</script>
```

Submitting with this ajax

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#txtEditor").Editor();
            $("#txtEditor").Editor("setText", "Hello World");
            }); 

var message = window.btoa($("#txtEditor").Editor("getText"));
// Javascript decode


$.post( "test.php", { message: message })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });


<textarea id="txtEditor"></textarea>
```

test.php
php encode

```
$message = base64_decode($_POST['message']);
OR 
Javascript encode
var message = window.atob(message);
```

For beginners like me, detail is needed

Thank you again to everyone